# Версии python в atom linux(ubuntu/mint)

Tags: python, linux, atom

У меня есть несколько версий python. У меня linux mint. Я использую редактор кода atom с расширением atom-python-run. Я хочу запустить версию python3.7. Когда я запускаю код из pycharm он показывет путь /usr/bin/python3.7, как сделать такую же python версию в atom?

Comment: python3 --version
выдает 3.6

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: поменять версию python, https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux
Спасибо KoVadim

Comment: Лучше не трогать стандартный системный интерпретатор: системные утилиты могут использовать пакеты, работающие только на той версии python3, которая установлена сейчас. Можно случайно сломать себе систему.